# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith' in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a below function which works fine in Chrome but its giving the below error in IE10
`SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'`

```
function getUrlParameter(URL, param){
    var paramTokens = URL.slice(URL.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < paramTokens.length; i++) {
    var urlParams = paramTokens[i].split('=');
    if (urlParams[0].endsWith(param)) {
        return urlParams[1];
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with this function?

Comment: Read the support table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: `endsWith` simply isn't supported by IE10.

Comment: @FelixKling How do I make it work in IE10?

Comment: Implement the `endsWith` logic yourself.

Comment: Or use the one that Firefox gives you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Implemented `endsWith` as below

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(pattern) {
  var d = this.length - pattern.length;
  return d >= 0 && this.lastIndexOf(pattern) === d;
};
```

Comment: Wrap it with `if (!String.prototype.endsWith)` and note that `endsWith` takes an extra argument, `position` "Optional. Search within this string as if this string were only this long; defaults to this string's actual length, clamped within the range established by this string's length."

Comment: Saved my day. You deserve a bounty.

Answer (score 20):

You should use the following code to implement `endsWith` in browsers that don't support it:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(search, this_len) {
        if (this_len === undefined || this_len > this.length) {
            this_len = this.length;
        }
        return this.substring(this_len - search.length, this_len) === search;
    };
}
```

This is directly from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) and is standards-compliant, unlike the other answer given so far.

Comment: You are right, we should be checking official Polyfills from MDN. Btw polyfill was updated, [new proposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill) is there.

Answer (score 0):

IE v.11 and below does not support some of the ES6 properties like set, endsWith etc. So you need to add polyfills for individual ES6 properties.
To ease the process you can use some compiler like **Babel JS** or external libraries like  **polyfill.js** etc.

For ends with add below snippet before the  tag in your index.html or before bundling happens.

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      }
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```